# How to make the arrows longer

Tags: arrows

For years and years I have been using `\longmapsto` and `\longrightarrow` and their brothers and sisters.
On this site, I found the following commands to obtain arrows for surjections and injections:
`\newcommand{\surj}{\mathrel{\mathrel{\mathrlap{\relbar\joinrel\rightarrow}\mkern1mu\rightarrow}}}` and
`\newcommand{\inj}{\lhook\joinrel\longrightarrow}`.

However, I am not satisfied about the length of the arrows, I think they are too short.

This is an excerpt from a [syllabus](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/%7Emaudin/analysecomp.pdf) by the French mathematician Michèle Audin. I very much like the length of here arrows.

[image]

Is it possible to have variants of the above four with length adapted in this way? Is it also possible to have arrows of this length and `\stackrel{}{}` being compatible with it?

Comment: These are way too long for no real purpose, in my opinion.

Comment: For the arrow length, you can use `\xrightarrow{\hspace{some length}}` and  `\xmapsto{\hspace{same length}}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep adding `\joinrel\relbar` until you get the desired length.

But don't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\loongrightarrow}{%
  \DOTSB\relbar\joinrel\relbar\joinrel\rightarrow
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\loongmapsto}{\DOTSB\mapstochar\loongrightarrow}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\looongrightarrow}{%
  \DOTSB\relbar\joinrel\relbar\joinrel\relbar\joinrel\rightarrow
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\looongmapsto}{\DOTSB\mapstochar\looongrightarrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}[t]
\varphi\colon
\mathcal{O}(U) &\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(D) \\
f              &\mapsto     f|_D
\end{aligned}\tag{good}
\\
\begin{aligned}[t]
\varphi\colon
\mathcal{O}(U) &\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}(D) \\
f              &\longmapsto     f|_D
\end{aligned}\tag{bad}
\\
\begin{aligned}[t]
\varphi\colon
\mathcal{O}(U) &\loongrightarrow \mathcal{O}(D) \\
f              &\loongmapsto     f|_D
\end{aligned}\tag{worse}
\\
\begin{aligned}[t]
\varphi\colon
\mathcal{O}(U) &\looongrightarrow \mathcal{O}(D) \\
f              &\looongmapsto     f|_D
\end{aligned}\tag{ugly}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added random tags if you want to refer to the arrows when discussing them. They have no connection with my actual feelings about them.

Comment: A better way to construct longer arrows is to adapt the definitions of `\xleftarrow` or `\xrightarrow` and use a space of the desired width as the argument.  Using multiple segments of `\joinrel` and `\relbar` is tortured.